# How do I count the number of a list appears in another list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list named A:

```py
A = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and I want to count the number of list [1, 2] appears in A.
It will be 3 because:

```py
A = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    [1, 2][1, 2][1, 2] <- appears 3 times
```

Here is my code:

```py
result = 0
while len(A) > 0:
temp, tA = [1, 2], A
    for i in temp:
        if len(tA) == 0: break
        if i in tA: tA.pop(0)
    result += 1
return result
```

And I wonder know is there any faster way to accomplish the same function?

Comment: Tip: simply check for each slice of your list if it is equal to the sublist

Comment: You are overthinking this. [Here's a very simple solution](https://pastebin.com/pzYX3sEB). You could also chunk your list in pairs of two if you want to get a bit more fancy. There are lots of existing questions about chunking here.

Comment: have a look at [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) followed by [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: @Rabinzel OP does not need (A, B), (B, C), (C, D), ... but (A, B), (C, D), ...

Comment: @timgeb yes, with a BUT. Maybe I'm wrong, but does it make a difference here? pairwise detects "more" than needed, but checking the keys (which are the tuples) in the counter results in the right number of occurences of the target pair.

Comment: @Rabinzel yes, the result will be the same. But if you're leveraging fancy iteration techniques, why not go all the way with `itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(A)]*2)`? :D

Comment: @timgeb I literally just at that moment found an answer where this line of code was provided for dividing the list into pairs of two :D. Seems like the more straightforward way.

Comment: @Rabinzel I think the straight forward way is the pastebin I posted, especially at OP's level of experience. ;)

Comment: @timgeb true again. timgeb 1, Rabinzel 0 :D